# Add a textbox field to an XFA form using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I have an `Adobe LiveCycle form` based on the `XML Forms Architecture` (XFA).

I want to add a input field to it programmatically using c#.

I tried many ways to do so but not able to add a field to an existing `XFA form`.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your question because it was riddled with errors. You wrote XFD, but it's XFA: the [XML Forms Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFA) (or XDP, [XML Data Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Data_Package)). XFA means that you have XML wrapped in PDF; with XDP, it's the other way around.

If you want to add a text field to an XFA form, you need to do this at the XML level. iText is a PDF library: it doesn't allow you to add a text field to an XFA form, because it doesn't manipulate the XML. In theory, you could remove the XML from the PDF using iText, manipulate it with an XML tool to add a text field, and then put the XML back into the PDF using iText, but I don't know of any tool that implements the XFA spec in a way that the XML manipulation is easy.

I only see two options for you:

- If your form is a pure XFA form, please abandon all hope that you will be able to add a field programmatically. Buy yourself a license of Adobe LiveCycle Designer, and add the field manually.
- If your form is a hybrid, consisting of XFA and AcroForm technology, then [throw away the XFA part](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/it-safe-remove-xfa) and add the text field as an AcroForm field.

Note that XFA is deprecated in ISO 32000-2:2017. I know of only two products that support XFA: Adobe LiveCycle (for the creation, manipulation, filling, and flattening of XFA forms) and iText's pdfXFA (for filling and flattening). I highly recommend you to abandon the XFA technology. As it is deprecated, all support for the format will soon be discontinued.